# How to access files from this hierarchy?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp

I need to access from the jsp files which are in WebContent/jsp folder, to the *.css file which is in WebContent/css.

And I've tried using `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/adminStyle.css"`. But, sometimes the *.css works and sometimes it doesn't.

Another thing is how do I access from a *.css file to an image in imgs folder. And I tried using `background-image:url('../imgs/background.png');`

The hierarchy is the following:

WebContent

```
 css
  |
  +--->  adminStyle.css

 imgs
  |
  +--->  background.png

 jsp
  |
  +--->  admin.jsp
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes the css works"?

Comment: You should write your URLs like the following href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/adminStyle.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sometimes the css works and sometimes not" looks like you it works for some url and doesn't work for some url. for this @rickz answer will work

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/adminStyle.css"
```

This will eliminate the possibility of breaking css import with regards of url

for second question "how do I access from a css file to an image in imgs folder"

```
background-image:url('../imgs/background.png');
```

because relative path of background image defined in css will start from the folder where your css file is.